# How to wait a method to finish in RxJava2 to execute the next one

Tags: android, android-intent, synchronization, wait, rx-java2

I'm doing a call to a method that stores some info in SharedPreferences and the next line is an intent to another Activity, I am not able to store anything at this point, and I think that the Intent is doing faster than the save of the info, so after call the finish/intent to a new activity the sharedpreference has no time to finish the operation and doesn't write anything.

```
persistUserAuth(userAuth);
openHomeActivity();
```

How I can do this 2 methods synchronous to make the second method to wait to finish to the first method in RxJava2??

Thank you.

Comment: did you call apply or commit saving in your persistUserAuth method ?

Comment: apply to put the object

Comment: what do you mean by *I am not able to store anything at this point* ?

Comment: In the next activity SharedPreferences hasn't anything of the userauth that I was storing in the previous activity. So, I think that the problem is that the method has not finished when the intent open the new activity

Comment: post code of `persistUserAuth ` method also.

Comment: In your SharedPreferences editor, you can use `commit()` instead of `apply()` so that the call will be synchronous.